# Life bar resize with slider Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I am trying to setup a life bar in Unity by using the `Slider` component. The hierarchy is the following:

[image: Life bar Hierarchy]

I have as Fill and Border two `Images`, with custom sprites I did. The Fill object is the colored bar, while the Border object contains only the borders for the life bar.

I fixed the borders of the Fill sprite in the Sprite Editor as follows:

[image: Sprite editor borders]

Then, in the Health Bar object I added a `Slider` component to manage the bar resize. The `Slider` component in the Inspector is as follows:

[image: Slider component in the inspector]

The aspect of the life bar without any resize is the following:

[image: Life bar aspect]

However, I have a problem with the resize of the lifebar. When I resize it, it behaves like this:

[image: Resize strange behavior]

How can I avoid this behavior? I want the bar to stay inside the borders.

Comment: You can also use Image component with ImageType set to `Filled`. If Slider is not needed specifically.

Comment: I had the same issue a few years ago and I fixed it by using an Image component and set the 'ImageType' to 'Filled' as @msaiduraz suggest.

Comment: So you are telling me essentially to remove the `Slider` component and use a `Filled Image` in its place? And to rescale it basing on the current life value should I change its scale?

Answer (score 0):

In my projects, I use such kind of auxiliary component for my images. But I'm not sure it is the best way to solve such problem.

```cs
[ExecuteInEditMode]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Image))]
public class ImagePpuScaler : MonoBehaviour
{

    private enum ScaleAxis
    {
        X,
        Y
    }

    [SerializeField] private float _scaleFactor = 1f;

    [SerializeField] private ScaleAxis _scaleAxis = ScaleAxis.Y;

    private Image _image;
    
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _image = GetComponent<Image>();
        Update();
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        OnEnable();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!_image.sprite)
            return;
        var border = _image.sprite.border;
        var maxBorder = Mathf.Max(border.x, border.y, border.z, border.w);
        float imgSize;
        if (_scaleAxis == ScaleAxis.Y)
        {
            imgSize = _image.rectTransform.rect.size.y;
        }
        else
        {
            imgSize = _image.rectTransform.rect.size.x;
        }

        _image.pixelsPerUnitMultiplier = maxBorder / (imgSize / 2f) * _scaleFactor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sliced image type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2esV.png)

Hi,
check if your "Fill" image component is of type Sliced.

**Edited:**
Try to use a standard Slider by adding it via context menu -> UI -> Slider, and set your sprites instead of the default.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzYjf.png)

Comment: Yes, it is of `Sliced` tipe

Comment: I edited the answer, on the screenshot you can find how exactly you can set your image instead of the default one (on the third Slider component)